# Extend a reset function from a base class in a derived class

Tags: c++

I have the following classes with a "reset" functionality.
The base class resets some things which are for all derived classes the same. This code should stay in the base class, so new childs don't have to reimplement it.
The derived class must implement its own reset function where it can put reset-code which is specific for this derived class.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
class Base
{
  public:
    Base(){}
    virtual ~Base()
    {
      std::cerr << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
      resetBase();
    }
    virtual void reset() = 0;
  protected:
    void resetBase()
    {
      // reset actions which are the same for all derived classes
      std::cerr << "Base::" << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

class A : public Base
{
  public:
    A(){}
    ~A()
    {
      std::cerr << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
    void reset() override
    {
      resetBase();
      std::cerr << "A::" << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
      // reset actions which are specific for this derived class
      mValueA = -1;
    }
  private:
    int mValueA = 0;
};

int main()
{
  Base* a = new A{};
  a->reset();
  delete a;
}
```

Output:

```
Base::resetBase
A::reset
~A
~Base
Base::resetBase
```

The code works, but I'm unsatisfied with the design.
I see the following problems:

- If objects are deleted, only the resetBase() function is called. This is currently not so bad, since the objects are destroyed anyway. But it would be nicer if the reset function from the derived class would be called automatically anyway.
- Every new child class has to make sure to call resetBase() in its reset() function. It would be nice if this happens automatically.

Is there a better way to extend a base reset functionality?

Comment: `virtual` functions are ignored in constructors/destructors, for good reason - `A` doesn't exist anymore by the time `~Base()` is called. I don't see why you want to call `reset` in destructor anyway - unless it releases some resources, it's pointless to do that, and if it does, you must take care of the resource in the class that owns it anyway, there's no way to delegate it to base class.

Comment: You could have the derived class implement a `protected` function, e.g. `resetDerived`, and call this function from a non-virtual `Base::reset` function. You should ***not*** call any reset functionality relating to derived classes in the base class destructor, since at that time the derived class portion of the object has already been destroyed making any access undefined behaviour.

Comment: the `resetBase()` function triggers a message to the outside world, which should be triggerd before the object is deleted. But I also want to trigger this message without deleting the object. Therefore the code has been swapped out of the destructor into a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can change your design to automate the resetBase() call using the "non-virtual interface" (NVI) idiom.

The NVI idea is to make the interface of a class non-virtual and then delegate to one or more pure virtual functions for the implementation, allowing the base class to ensure some invariant or common code is always executed, without requiring derived classes to remember to do so and stuff.

Appllying this idea in your case:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base()
    {
        std::cerr << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        resetBase();
    }
    void reset()
    {
        resetBase();
        doReset();
    }
protected:
    virtual void doReset() = 0;
private:
    void resetBase()
    {
        std::cerr << "Base::" << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

class A : public Base
{
public:
    A() {}
    ~A()
    {
        std::cerr << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
protected:
    void doReset() override
    {
        std::cerr << "A::" << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        mValueA = -1;
    }
private:
    int mValueA = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Base* a = new A{};
    a->reset();
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

The common resetBase() code is always run and the derived classes only have to implement resetImpl() for their specific reset functionality. Also the destructor of the base class doesn't need to call resetBase() any longer.

Comment: `void reset() final` doesnt work:
error: ‘void Base::reset()’ marked ‘final’, but is not virtual

Comment: Your solution is missing the reset line in the base destructor. `reset()` in destructor isn't allowed because of calling a pure virtual method (`resetImpl()`). `resetBase()` works, but I don't see much different to my solution.

Comment: Ah, yeah, sorry for that. resetImpl() is the one which is virtual and intended to be overridden, and we dont want any further overriding in classes derived from A, so the correct is to mark resetImpl() in A as final. I'll change the answer.

Comment: I agree NVI is the way to go, here. Why is `resetBase()` protected, though? It's obviously not meant to be touched by derived classes.

Comment: @Friedrich i agree, changing to private instead of protected would be a better design choice. I'll fix that :)

Comment: can you also add the `resetBase()` call to the Base destructor? Otherwise it hasn't the same behavior as the initial code.

Comment: @Käseknacker NVI doesn't look much different on the surface, but it does provide an extra level of control over the sequence of method calls, and simplify the interface for derived classes, as it reduces the need for them to remember to call a base class method.

Comment: @Käseknacker thanks for pointing the missing resetBase call, already fix that :)

Comment: NVI is probably the pattern I was looking for without knowing it existed. Thank you all for figuring out this solution. I love the internet :)

Comment: Update from my cpp training: doReset can and should be private!